# Insert value in enum PDO

Tags: php, html, pdo, prepared-statement

I want to insert values in db table enum attribute costtype enum('free', 'euro', 'tc'). My code inserts values from the first "if" even if I select another option. I will give both HTML and PHP code. I use PHP & PDO. Thank you in advance!!

HTML:

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Project Price <small>(You must also check a payment way from the list)</small></label>
          <select name="costtype[]" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="begins" title="Select a method">
                <option value="free">Free</option>
                <option value="euro">Euro </option>
                <option value="tc">Time Coins</option>                                                           
          </select>
</div>



$pdoQuery = "INSERT INTO project (pname, finishdate, description, username, cost, costtype) 
        VALUES (:projectname,:date_end,:description,:username,:costtype,:cost)";
```

PHP and PDO code:

```
$pdoResult = $pdo->prepare($pdoQuery);


foreach ($costtype as $ct ) {

if ($ct == $costfree)  {

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(

    ":projectname" => $projectname,
    ":date_end" => $date_end,
    ":description" => $description,
    ":username" => $username,
    ":costtype" => $costfree,
    ":cost" => $freecost


    ));

} elseif ($ct == $costeu) {

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(

    ":projectname" => $projectname,
    ":date_end" => $date_end,
    ":description" => $description,
    ":username" => $username,
    ":costtype" => $costeu,
    ":cost" => $cost


    ));
} else {

    $pdoExec = $pdoResult->execute(array(

    ":projectname" => $projectname,
    ":date_end" => $date_end,
    ":description" => $description,
    ":username" => $username,
    ":costtype" => $costtc,
    ":cost" => $cost


    ));


}
```

}

Comment: You set `:costtype` to be `$costfree`, and your first conditional checks against `$costfree`. Thus, the conditional will always be entered. You probably meant to set `:costtype` to `$costtype`, and the value for `free` to `$costfree`. Also, your inserted values are back to front.

Comment: Probably I am missing something, but I don;t get this. Basically you are doing

`if ( $a == $x ) do_something($x) ;
elseif ( $a == $y ) do_something($y) ;
elseif ( $a == $z ) do_something($z) ;`

I would say:
`do_something($a) ;`
Or, if you want to be sure $a is defined:

`do_something($a?:$z);`